# Angular5 stepper component with combination of horizontal and vertical steps

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

how to add vertical mat-step in horizontal stepper component?

Is it possible to add vertical step in the horizontal stepper component in angular 5?

I want stepper component like the below link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PHKV.png

Can you please suggest me what are possible ways to get the above stepper component.

Comment: have you tried anything? kindly share what you tried and the error/issue which you faced

Comment: Tried something like that which is not working, see below code in html <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
  <mat-step >
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Step1</ng-template>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step >
    <mat-vertical-stepper>
      <mat-step >
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Step2</ng-template>
       
      </mat-step >
      <mat-step >
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Step3</ng-template>
      </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step4</ng-template>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

Comment: You can edit your own question. Please, edit your question adding further information, your attempts, what you expected and what didn't work